# Should we add language tags to a question if it's applicable to other languages as well?

Tags: discussion, tags

Let's take a look at this example: [What does `for (;;)` mean in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737550/what-does-for-mean-in-perl/)

Currently this is tagged `[perl]` and `[loop]`, and yet the question and answer is also applicable to (I think) `[c++]`, `[java]`, `[c#]`, etc.

What should we do in these kinds of cases? Should we add language tags when the difference between the languages doesn't detract too much from the answer? (but how much is too much?).

What if adding these tags make the question a clear cut dupe? (I haven't looked for the dupe in this case, but I'm 100% confident I've seen a dupe of this `for (;;)` question for another language).

Comment: I think you should only tag using the single language that you are wanting to ask about (and presumably using).  If you are asking about multiple languages your question is probably too broad for focussed Q&A.

Answer (score 5):

Please don't multi-tag -- it leads to a lot of negative side effects like incorrect tag badge awards, incorrect stats, etc.

I suggest the [language-agnostic] tag (or something similar) instead of a mindless list of "every possible programming language this might ever apply to"

Comment: One would assume that retagging questions is part of a normal workflow for the site; didn't realize that it's such a harmful activity with "a lot of negative side effects". Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @polygene: I think it's not retagging itself that is the problem, it's just applying the _wrong_ tags. Like Jeff said, the question you asked about could/should have the `[perl]` tag changed to `[language-agnostic]`, but it shouldn't have a bunch of other language tags added.

Comment: The right tag would be something like [c-style-languages] or [c-based-languages], but neither exist yet so I didn't retag it. IMHO you'd probably want to change the question subject too, so it needs to be done by someone with more than just retag privs.